# Can't convert time in Java

Tags: java, datetime

I have a string in format "2017/07/20 16:20:03" with `psiUpdateForm.getUpdateTime()`, and column in table is Date type, when I update data, I used code as below

```
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
processor.addParameter(Types.DATE, fmt.parse(psiUpdateForm.getUpdateTime()));
```

But when I check table, data is in `2017/07/20 00:00:00`, what can I do?

Comment: What are `processor`, `psiUpdateForm` (does the method return exactly the string you said ?) ?

Comment: That's because you are using `Types.DATE` which corresponds to the SQL DATE type, which is just a date without time. Use `Types.TIMESTAMP` instead.

Comment: mikezang, please edit your question and give the context. @Jesper seems to know what you are talking about, but some of us are in the dark.

Comment: @jesper Thanks a lot! pls answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant `Types.DATE` corresponds to the SQL type DATE, which is a date without a time.

To store date and time, use `Types.TIMESTAMP` instead.

Of course, the column in the database must also be of the correct type so that it can store a date and time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save date and time, use java `DateTime` / sql `TimeStamp` instead of `Date`.